# Ubuntu on MacBook: Power Usage

Tags: mouse, suspend, backup, power-management, macbook-air

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Apple MacBook Air (2015).
The two major problems I face issue with Battery Backup.

The battery backup has been significantly reduced to 2-3 hours. The OsX was comfortably giving me 7-8 hours backup. Another strange thing I noticed is that, even if put my laptop on sleep mode (with full charge), the battery becomes empty after a couple of hours. It seems some applications wakes up frequently and consume the power. Do we have any application which will show the battery consumption for a long time, for example for lat 24 hours (or during a full discharge cycle)?
I found powertop, but it gives only the statistics when the system is on (not sleep).

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Both problems can be solved and you can find solutions is you search. Sleep mode consumes power, it is normal. There is hibernate mode that doesn't.

Comment: @Pilot6 I edited the question as per your suggestion and kept only one question now. I could not get any solutionveven after Googling for sometime.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: There is a ton of answers about improving battery time. Install `laptop-mode-tools`. That will automatically improve it. To check power consumption use `powertop`.

Comment: output of lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' is:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915

Comment: @Pilot6 I have already installed and tried laptop-mode-tools. As I have mentioned in my question, I tried powertop also. But it will not give the statistics for a long time (for a complete discharge cycle.

Comment: You did not edit the question, but posted the output to a comment box. `powertop` shows power consumption of each system component, if you press Tab a few times and get to that screen.